# NetBeans 7.4 cannot find symbol error when importing java.net.URLEncoder

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

I am using NetBeans 7.4 with JDK 7u51.

When I try to compile the below statement:

```
package userclasses;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
```

etc... Other imports.
etc... Normal class definition.

I get this compile error message:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import java.net.URLEncoder;
  symbol:   class URLEncoder
  location: package java.net
```

If I take the `import java.net.URLEncoder` out of the file then it compiles fine.
I have tried clearing the NetBeans cache.

The only thing I can think of is that the compiler is searching the wrong java.net library.
I am using `codenameone libraries` and one of them contains a `java.net` definition with only a few classes in it.  I am not sure if this is legal?  Seems like that could obscure the JDK's `java.net` library?  However, I completely removed that library from the project and still get the same error, so that discredits my theory a bit, though it could be defined somewhere else that I am unaware of.

I am open to any suggestions?

BTW does any know which physical library file java.net classes are located in?
I was thinking of adding that `.jar` to my project and placing it first on the `classpath` (I know that it is included with the JDK by default), that way I would know for sure that the correct java.net was being searched.

This is frustrating stuff as my development work has ground to a complete halt because of this.

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that java.net.URLEncoder is not supported with codenameone platform, at least not as of version 2.0.  Codenameone has a class called com.codename1.io.Util.encodeUrl that works.